# Is there a fast alternative to "ORDER BY RAND()" that does not require evenly distributed integers as primary keys?

Tags: mysql

I want to extract a random row of a table. Using "ORDER BY RAND" and taking the first row is slow because a separate table is created. The standard alternative is to rely on a unique primary index that has to be an integer.

However, this does not return good results if the primary keys aren't evenly distributed. Additionally, it requires that I maintain an additional column of integers.

Comment: http://blog.statvoo.com/post/113967722206/order-by-rand-faster-alternative

Answer (score 1):

I have done some random selection in T-SQL with unevenly distributed keys that does not require an additional column to be added, this is how:

1. Check how many valid rows there are in the table (`COUNT(...)`)
2. Randomize a number between 1 and the number of rows
3. Query the row using the random number as an index

Comment: But how do I query the n-th row of table without having a column enumerating the rows?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM 'table' LIMIT n , 1`

Answer (score 0):

Even if your primary keys aren't evenly distributed, you can still make sure of them by an open-ended range query:

```
SELECT thing FROM table WHERE pk_id > 134 LIMIT 1;
```

Even if there is no row that has a key of 134, you'll get the next one in the chain. The nice thing about this approach is that it's a simple range scan and highly efficient. You also do not need to know how many rows are in the table (say via a `SELECT COUNT(*)` ...), which is costly when using InnoDB - and you should be using InnoDB). You DO need to do the max row id, but that's efficient to grab (`SELECT MAX(pk_id) FROM table`) and can be cached.

Comment: As I understand it, you select the first row with an index bigger than 134? To make it random, 134 has to be replaced by a random number?    This has two drawbacks: First, it assumes that the rows are sorted by primary key. (Are they? I don't know that much about mysql). Second, which is worse, it STILL requires an even distribution of primary keys. Imagine all primary keys gather between 900 and 1000, but the random numbers are created evenly between 0 and 1000. The row with pk = 900 will be selected in 90% of all cases.